# Counter for theorem/lemma

Tags: hyperref, counters, cleveref

I'm trying to use only one counter for theorems, lemma etc. Normally my code should work but I got a mistake

> "Latex error : no counter 'l'  defined".

My guess is that I probably use a package which is not compatible with this counter but I'm not sure which one. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Proof}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
test
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hyperref` package is loaded here after `cleveref`, which confuses the `counter` and `cross-reference` system.

Using the correct load order `hyperref` → `cleveref` solves this problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Proof}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
test
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```